# textView.typingAttributes not working for prediction

Tags: ios, swift3, attributes, uitextview, xcode8

I have a textview which is filled with some default text in blue, now my goal is, whatever edit I make in the text it should come in red color. I'm using `texView.typingAttributes` to achieve this and it works almost well, except if I use prediction or autocorrect starting from any words that are in blue, in this case the predicted or auto corrected word still remains in blue. If I use prediction outside the blue area it works fine. Is there anything else that I should do for prediction? Below is my current code that I use to achieve this.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    textView.typingAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.red

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Correction, you need to apply the *color attribute* property for selected range of the string. It's working now, added the code as below:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    textView.typingAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.red

    let colorAttribute = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red]
    textView.textStorage.addAttributes(colorAttribute, range: range)

        return true
    }
```

Comment: This almost works, but problem is that if you select a blue text in between and use the prediction the cursor goes somewhere else. Also, selecting and pasting on blue text also don't work.

Comment: @sonu, But as you asked in question: **if I use prediction or autocorrect starting from any words that are in blue, in this case the predicted or auto corrected word still remains in blue**, now that color problem got solved. corrected word becomes red instead of blue.

Comment: Yes, but if I use this solution it creates a new problem of cursor position which was not there before.

Comment: @sonu, solved that cursor positioning problem and updated the code for the same. it's working fine. Feel free to ask if any query...